# Reading a changing txt file matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a text file (5 columns "\t" separated)  that's being written to by another software. I need to take the readings from the file and do some calculations. Is there a was to read the new lines added to the file and process it then repeat again for every new set of lines. I don't mind a bit of delay as long as it does the job.

My idea is to start reading the file line by line until the end of file, then it will read from where it stopped last until the new end of file ...etc.
Can this be done in Matlab? Can I specify the starting line for the file reading? can I also update the end of file point?

To prevent the loop from breaking at the eof point, I think I should set my loop to be controlled by time or anything else, while it should check for eof at the end of every iteration.

I've mostly worked with Matlab, but if there is a better option to use for this purpose (that I can reasonably learn) please feel free to guide me.

Edit1: I've tried using dlmread as you suggested, when I read the file outside the loop it reads the file correctly even when I change R1 and with the other software updating the text. However, when I put it in a loop I get this error:
Error using dlmread (line 143)
Empty format string is not supported at the end of a file.

Here is my code to read it multiple times:

```
    clear all
x=0;
R1=0; C1=0;
while(x<10)

    M = dlmread('tst_4.txt','\t',R1,C1);
    R1=length(M);
    x=x+1;
end
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try to use `dlmread` and specify the range to read the data based on your last reading of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used [dlmread(filename,delimiter,R1,C1)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html). Where R1 and C1 are the row and column offset respectively. By setting the row offset to the last row that you have read, you can read the file content excluding what you would have already read.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it without a loop (changing R1 eveny time) and it worked, howevere when I put it in the loop and run the program that logs the data it gives this error: Error using dlmread (line 143)
Empty format string is not supported at the end of a file. I still can read the file (while being editted by the other software on single manaual iterations with R set to different values. Do you know why is this happening? I'll edit the post by putting my code. Thanks

Comment: Im not sure. I will try it out myself later on and let you know if I manage to solve the problem. In the meantime, I noticed a possible bug in your code. You are using length(M) to get the number of rows in the matrix. However the length function returns the length of the longest side. Since the number of rows is increasing as time goes by, it is possible that in the beginning you will have more columns than rows. This would mean that in the following loop, R1 would correspond to the number of columns. Try using size(M,1) instead to make sure that you are always getting the number of rows

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and I got no errors, I run it for 50 secs and I was able to read around 4000 lines which is great. My concern is that I couldn't see the size updating on the worksheet,does that mean that the processing can't be done until the reading is done?

Comment: dlmread should be able to read changes in the file as soon as they are updated. I ran a simple test by running dlmread inside a while loop, reading two columns of numbers from a csv file and outputting their sum. As soon as I make changes in the file and save it, the sum gets updated accordingly. This leads me to believe that your problem is within your logic and not dlmread. I suggest you mark this question as answered and opening another question with your problem if need be, otherwise we will get out of topic from the original question.